# policyd-spf is rejecting mail with '?all' SPF records

Tags: postfix, spf

One of our clients is getting mail rejected from one of his customers. The sender's SPF record is:

```
v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:12.34.56.78 ?all
```

The mail is not originating from 12.34.56.78, but AFAIU the '?all' means my mail server (postfix) should accept it. Is that correct?

Can I change my '/etc/postfix-policyd-spf-python/policyd-spf.conf' to make it accept these emails, and if so how?

Should I do this?

FWIW the message in py error log is:

```
Message rejected due to: access neither permitted nor denied.
```

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

My SPF policy was:

```
HELO_reject = SPF_Not_Pass
Mail_From_reject = Fail
```

The mail was being rejected at the HELO stage, which I've changed now to 'Fail'.

Comment: Please update this with the relevant parts of your policy if you still cannot resolve this issue. Also verify the SPF record can be resolved from your MTA server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The mail is not originating from 12.34.56.78, but AFAIU the '?all' means my mail server (postfix) should accept it. Is that correct?

Yes, but not **should**, just **intended**

From [here](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax), you can see that `Neutral` means `The SPF record specifies explicitly that nothing can be said about validity`

But the default SPF policy from postfix is that:

```
HELO_reject = SPF_Not_Pass
```

means the postfix will reject HELO if SPF check not pass ( i.e Fail, Softfail, Hardfail...)

You can change postfix SPF policy to accept email even SPF check fail.

Comment: I think the default policies vary by distribution don't they?

Comment: No, every postfix version I have used also have the same default SPF policy is `HELO_reject = SPF_Not_Pass`

Comment: So in this case, where I want this mail to come through, but still want some level of protection I'd want to use Fail for this setting?

Comment: No, if you want some protection, please make SPF check pass. But you should remember, SPF (or DKIM) is only optional on testing spam mail. As far as I know, the important when checking mail spam is blacklist, contetn-encoding (7-bit), PTR record.

Comment: Sorry, when you say 'please make SPF check pass' you mean set HELO_reject to SPF_Not_Pass` (as it currently is?), or do you mean I should accept mail (at this stage) no matter what the SPF, and let later parts of the system (eg amavis) sort it all out?

Comment: Yes, let it defaults to some protection. Or if you trurst your partner, you can put their emails in white list of your mail server

Comment: You will probably want to go with HELO_reject = Fail, to match the Mail_From_reject setting.  I find SPF_Not_Pass to be too restrictive for HELO checking.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track.  The inclusion of the ?all policy is simply stating a preference on how the sender wishes the mail to be handled. How it is actually handled is determined by your system.

You have not posted your policy but you can set it to allow this domain or this condition by modifying your policy.

See:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/policyd-spf.conf.5.html

Note some policy conditions will reject email if the SPF cannot be determined (e.g. formatting error with the SPF record itself or DNS issue).